# Saving hundreds of pdf documents into database using .Net application

Tags: .net, pdf

I have asp.net application to upload multiple pdf files to Sybase database. But it's time consuming to upload hundreds of them. What's the best way to go about this task? I can bring the docs on my local system first. So I can use windows application too for this or any other option.....The time consuming part is clicking on browse button then selecting and then again browse button.....I want to have like check boxes against 800 documents that I want to save at one time.

Comment: Need a few more bits of info. a) what have you tried? b) how are they stored in the database? c) what's the database schema?

Comment: What's the most time-consuming part of the process?

Comment: @mellamokb: My assumption is it's a web front-end with a `[browse]`, locate the file (in a folder of hundreds, that hasn't already been uploaded), then click `[ok]` and finally `[submit]`. Though I'm only speculating.

Comment: yeah clicking on browse then ok for each document. I want to select all the 800 documents at once and save them in one click if possible.

Comment: @Brad: Right now they are in file system. I am trying to save them in database along with other related information for each document.

Comment: @Learner: Does the database store the file itself (e.g. a binary column) or just a pointer to the file (e.g. file path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get them all in the same directory on your local machine you can use:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
```

to get the list of all of the documents and then just use a for loop to grab each file and convert it to a byte stream and add it to the database. You would not even need a winforms application. A simple console application would do the trick.